# how to read the contact name in messages?

Tags: android

I search something but its not working its show a red mark on cursor.Please correct these error .Thanks in advance .Is this correct method to get the complete contact name list?

```
  String address = (here its show error )cursor.getString(**cursor**.getColumnIndex("address"));

    final String[] projection = new String[] {ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};

    String displayName = null;
    Cursor contactCursor = null;

    try {
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                Uri.encode(address));

        contactCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                projection,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        if (contactCursor != null && contactCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            displayName = contactCursor.getString(
                    contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(contactCursor != null) {
            contactCursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: have u added required permissions? and request them in runtime?

Comment: No but when i write this line  String address = (here its show error )cursor.getString(**cursor**.getColumnInde the cursor shows in red format ? is there add any gradle ?

Answer (score 1):

if you didn't set permissions to read contacts so add this to Manifest before `<application/>` tag

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

and for android API 23+ you need to add this to you java class before try to ask

```
requestpermissions(Manifest.android.permissions.READ_CONTACTS, 0/*int*/);
```